# Unmanaged ODP.NET - BulkCopy Guid to RAW(16)

Tags: c#, database, oracle, plsql, guid

I'm trying to insert data from CSV File to Oracle DB with OracleBulkCopy.

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE CodeDictionary
(
    Id                      RAW(16) default SYS_GUID(),
    Code                    varchar2(100) NULL,
    Description             varchar2(300) NULL,
    Domain                  varchar2(100) NOT NULL,

    constraint PK_CodeDictionary PRIMARY KEY (Id)
) GO
```

I can not insert .Net Guid as RAW(16) with BulkCopy.

This is a piece of code:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable(_tableName);
// csvMapping(dataTable);
dataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(byte[]));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Domain", typeof(string));

using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
{
    oracleConnection.Open();
    // Create the bulk copy object
    var oracleBulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(oracleConnection, OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction)
    {
        DestinationTableName = _tableName,
        BatchSize = _batchsize,
        BulkCopyTimeout = _oracleTimeOut
    };

    oracleBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");
    oracleBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Description", "Description");
    oracleBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Code", "Code");
    oracleBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Domain", "Domain");

    // WHILE (!textFieldParser.EndOfStream) 

    // Read CSV and Map data HERE.....

    dataTable.Rows.Add(formatRow);

    // **formatRow** is object[]
    // The first element of formatRow is 'Id' and is a byte[] generated in that way:
    // var guid = Guid.Parse("GUID_READ_FROM_CSV")
    // guid.ToByteArray();

    // END WHILE

    oracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

    oracleConnection.Close();
}
```

This code give me this exception:
***ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kpudpxp_isSid-2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []***

I have tried to create table without RAW(16) and BulkCopy work prefectly, so I think that the problem is *Guid -> byte[] -> RAW(16)*.

I have also tried with **OracleBinary** type but with no success.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Maybe someone who has already used this OracleBulkCopy several times.
For me it's the first time I work with Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Funny, I hit this issue many years ago and I sincerely hoped Oracle has fixed it. Apparently not. There is some issue with the mapping but if the size constraint is higher than 16 bytes it works fine. So if you can redefine the ID column as RAW(17) your code will work.